# Facebook App size, how to control it?

Tags: facebook

I've tried disabling geolocalization, yet the data portion of the apps is by far the largest storage hog in my phone (140Mb as I type). I uninstalled the facebook messenger app because it was also taking a lot of storage, any idea why facebook need so much data stored locally in our phones?

Any idea how to put a limit to it? (what else could I disable?)

Comment: It's probably caching a lot of data, and any pictures you may download from Facebook. Settings>Applications>Facebook>Clear cache might be worth a go.

Comment: @RossC The FB app consumes a lot of space even with the cache cleared, mainly because for some reason the app unpacks a lot of `.dex` files onto its `/data/data/com.facebook.katana` folder.

Comment: @aureljared ahh that makes a lot of sense, what a total pain. I know they have some "intelligent work arounds" in their app, that amount to slowdown and bloat in reality. For the OP there's always the option of using the facebook mobile site, which is often better than the app!

Comment: thanks for the comments, yes I've cleared the cache many times (with the pain of having to set all settings (such as username/password or the no auto-playing of videos). I uninstalled the messenger app for a similar reason. I also disable contact sync thinking it could be related, but it keeps creeping out, slowly but surely. I cleared a week ago  (so I could install some updates) and it currently at 83MB.

Comment: I know this is not the answer to your question but I deleted a lot of IMs from the Messenger app and I did see a bit of a difference. However the amount of time and effort don't really pay off. I thought audio clips would be the answer but I managed to clear the ridiculously low amount of 1mb. I guess what I will do next is clear all my searches and maybe delete old, unnecessary pictures, recent activity and posts. Hmmm never thought about it till now.. it just might work.

Comment: I've stopped using all of facebook apps, I found the mobile webapp (m.facebook.com using chrome) suits my needs (I'm missing the notifications though)